# how to restore oracle data backup

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Recently, the HD of my computer was having problems. My oracle 10g xe was installed and running in this HD.

But I performed a copy of the DBF files in the folder "oradata\XE", before the HD stop functioning. These files are:
CONTROL.DBF ,SYSAUX.DBF,SYSTEM.DBF,TEMP.DBF,UNDOTBS1.DBF,USERS.DBF

I wonder if is possible to recover my data from these files. Or, if is possible to import the data in this files to a new installation of Oracle 10g.
I have all users and passwords.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.
Best Regards.

Comment: Was the database instance running when you copied the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, no problem. As long as you made the copy while the database was offline. Copy the files to the same PATH on a new drive. Oracle records the locations of the datafiles (fully qualified) in the controlfile. Assuming that CONTROL.DBF is your controlfile, start with making a init.ora that contains

```
control_files='d:\some\dir\CONTROL.dbf'
dbname='your_db_name'
```

you might need some other parameters, add what you need.

1. go to the command prompt
2. make sure that ORACLE_HOME points to the directory where your software is installed
3. Make sure that your PATH variable starts with %ORACLE_HOME%\bin
4. sqlplus / as sysdba
5. startup pfile=d:\where\you\put\it\init.ora

and see what happens. Most likely it is complaining about missing redolog files.
IT the db complains about the logs, it is already mounted. Check the logs using:

```
select group#, archived, status from v$log;
```

Depending on the status and archived colums of each group# issue
If STATUS = INACTIVE and ARCHIVED = YES

```
alter database clear logfile group <grp number>;
```

If STATUS = INACTIVE and ARCHIVED = NO
STATUS = INACTIVE and ARCHIVED = NO

```
alter database clear UNARCHIVED logfile group <grp number>;
```

If that succeeds, open the database

```
alter database open;
```

during the clear logfile the missing logfiles are created.

Comment: hi ik zelf i follow all the instructions that u say now an error show ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

Comment: What is in the alert log?

Comment: please guide me how to check alret log

Comment: when i use alter database open command;it shows error ora:-00312 online log1 thread 1 'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\flash_recovery_area\XE\ONLINELOG\01mf7z.log' unable to open file the system cannnot find the file specified

Comment: now when i use select group#, archived, status from v$log; it shows group#2 status unused,archive yes and other group#1 archive No,Status CLEARING CURRENT

Comment: hi ik zelf i found more simple solution i just simply copy my all dbf files to new installed db folder after follwing commands work for me 1.- Startup Mount
2.- Recover Until Cancel
3.- Alter Database Open Resetlogs

Now its working thank u very much u help me a lot